# Polymer autogrow textarea focus() not working

Tags: javascript, textarea, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using polymer's iron-autogrow-textarea. I was able to set the autofocus attribute and its working perfectly fine.

But when I try to set the focus back to textarea it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried

```
autoTextArea.focus();
```

It didn't work

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#autoTextArea')[0].focus();
    }, 1000);
```

This didn't work

```
    setTimeout(function() {
    $('#autoTextArea')[0].setAttribute('autofocus', true);
    }, 1000);
```

This obviously didn't work as autofocus only works on ready().

I have also tried to access the textArea inside the autogrow-textarea and even that didn't seem to be working.

Is there a way this can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code snippet where I am using it.

```
    'click #chatEnter': function(e, template) {
    var chatArea = $('#chatArea')[0];
    var chatTextArea = $('#chatTextArea')[0];

    if(chatTextArea.bindValue)
    {
        var chatNode = document.createElement('chat-message');
        chatNode.setAttribute('color', '#ff00ff');
        chatNode.setAttribute('avatar', '/src/someimage.jpg');
        chatNode.setAttribute('username', 'SomeName1');
        chatNode.setAttribute('text', chatTextArea.bindValue);
        chatNode.setAttribute('status',"MyStatus");
        chatNode.setAttribute('timestamp',"2015-07-12 12:00:00 AM");

        chatArea.appendChild(chatNode);
        chatTextArea.bindValue = "";
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('#chatTextArea')[0].setAttribute('autofocus', true);//.focus();
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Here is the HTML where I am using it.

```
    <section main layout vertical id="chat">
      <paper-material id="chatArea" elevation="1" animated style="overflow-y:scroll">
      </paper-material>
      <span layout horizontal>
        <paper-toolbar class="medium">
        <div>
          <iron-autogrow-textarea label="Enter message here" autocomplete="true" autofocus="true" maxRows=5 name="Text Area" id="chatTextArea">
            <textarea id="chatText" max-rows="5" ></textarea>
          </iron-autogrow-textarea>
        </div>
        <paper-icon-button raised icon="send" id="chatEnter"></paper-icon-button>
        <iron-a11y-keys keys="ctrl+enter" on-keys-pressed="[[enterKeyHandler]]"></iron-a11y-keys>
        </paper-toolbar>
      </span>
    </section>
```

Comment: Could you provide some more code? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I am using Polymer and Jquery (not heavily). And here is the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put a `textarea` tag inside `iron-autogrow-textarea`. The iron component is providing one. You can then access that inner textarea via `.textarea` and call focus on it.

Here's a small working example.

```
<body>
    <iron-autogrow-textarea rows="5"></iron-autogrow-textarea>
    <button>Focus!</button>

    <script>
        var button = document.querySelector('button');
        button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            console.log(document.querySelector('iron-autogrow-textarea'));
            var area = document.querySelector('iron-autogrow-textarea');
            area.textarea.focus();
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I've copy and pasted the code above (and played with variations of it over and over.) The only way I have been able to get focus or select to work on "area.textarea" is if a value is set before calling focus.  
i.e. if area.textarea.value = "something"
Am I going mad or is *anyone else* having this problem?

Comment: I don't experience that behaviour. You can find a link to plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFd7tcqdm2AtHI8Lv4V9?p=preview). Clicking the button will switch the focus between two textareas. The plunker only works in Chrome, but if I run the code from my server it also worksfine  in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To me more specific, I'm actually using paper-textarea which implements iron-autogrow-textarea. When I use the exact code you provided to access the iron-autogrow-textarea within the paper-textarea it doesn't seem to work. Using the same querySelector allows me to change the placeholder text so I know it is selecting the element correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem - when I navigated the page, the focus didn't return to the paper-textarea the second time I visited. After some looking at the DOM I came to the following solution:

```
    //focus textarea
    setTimeout(() => {
      //first working solution, line after that a bit more general
      // this.$.idOfPaperTextarea.shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-input-container').querySelector('#input-1').shadowRoot.querySelector('#textarea').focus();
      this.$.idOfPaperTextarea.shadowRoot.querySelector('iron-autogrow-textarea').shadowRoot.querySelector('textarea').focus();
    }, 0);
```

I guess the problem is that you have to get through the shadowRoots to access the textarea.